# Get current page visitors on document ready in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Today I was on a german delivery page for food because I was hungry. When I visited the page a popup was displayed which showed the current visitors on the page:

[image]

So I asked myself how the hell did they do that? So I tried to do some research in a huge JS file and found following:

---

This is a part of the function which builds this dialog:

```
getVisitorsTitle: function() {
    return this.getNumberOfVisitors() + " " + s("stickyNote.title")
   },
   getNumberOfVisitors: function() {
    var e, t;
    return t = this.bigCityList.indexOf(this.city) > -1 ? {
     max: 8,
     min: 2
    } : {
     max: 5,
     min: 2
    }, e = Math.floor(Math.random() * (t.max - t.min + 1)) + t.min, e = this.getVisitorBoost(e)
   }
```

So I'm not 100% sure but I think that the visitor counter is not a real counter. It's just a random number generated within a range. So this is a lie!

Now I'm asking myself if there is a way to get the current page visitors without faking it with a random number?

Answer (score 4):

The general approach is easy enough to visualize - whenever a user opens the page, open a [Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) (or something similar) so as to have two-way communication between the client and the server. Have the server count up the number of currently active Websocket connections it has for that page (from all clients, filtering out duplicate IP addresses if you want), and send data to the client whenever that number changes. The client can then update the appropriate number text in the browser.

Though, a Websocket isn't *necessary* - you could achieve the same sort of thing with repeated Ajax calls (eg. request the number from the server every couple minutes, and the server responds with the number of clients which have make requests in the past couple minutes), it would just be more messy.

Comment: This is easy to do with signalR, handles the Websocket if available, or falls back to long polling (repeated ajax requests) if not. Your server needs to track and store the connections but signalR handles this on the server as well, so you can easily push out updates to "subscribers" of a specific event, such as user connected/disconnected.

Comment: Also wtf SO. We aren't allowed to do `plus one` comments anymore? Had to use diff unicode character.

Comment: Sounds like I can't do it just with jQuery. This will be some huge coding right?

Comment: @Mr.Jo I don't think so, I'd think something like this could probably be done in less than 100 lines total, for the client and server code combined - it's quite straightforward. The difficulty would come from having to learn websocket or ajax syntax (if you aren't familiar with it already), and from having to figure out how to handle it in the back-end (in whichever language/framework), if you aren't familiar with it already. Requires *knowledge*, but not much *coding*

Comment: @CertainPerformance thats the point. I never worked with websocket and ajax combined. Especially in this case. The problem is that there is no solution out there which teaches me how to do this.